# jquery scrolling disrupts carousel controls

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery code to scroll to a specific div from the menu:

```
    $('a[href*=\\#]').bind('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(this).attr("href"); 
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 70
            }, 1000, function() {
            });

            return false;
    });
```

Alas it breaks bootstraps carousel functionality, binding the carousel controls anchor tags.

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
```

What might be a workaround?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Prefered way to declare events is: `.on('eventName'...` Events do not colide if:
1. You run them from parent and event bubbling is on
2. If you define it in other way eg. `.on('click'` does not colide with `elementSelector.onclick = function...`

Comment: After some thinking just try something smaller than `'a[href*=\\#]'` like specific id #ScrollToElement. Don't do this for all link elements with href containing # just for the one you want.

Comment: I want it to work for many menu items so the second comment won't do. I will try changing the anchor binding to elementSelector.onclick = function and give all relevant menu items a specific class.

Comment: Second comment will do just use classes not id's.

Comment: tried it before and it did not work. changed the first line to $('.scoller').('click', function(e) { and added class scroller to menu link.

Comment: `$('.scoller').('clic` will not work you forget about .on or .bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not uncommon to provide some form of identifier such as classes or data attributes when binding handlers to perform specific functionality.

Essentially you want hash bangs to scroll to other parts of the page. Here are some ways to accomplish this in order of preference (IMO).

**Data Attributes**

Data attributes are a great way to instantiate API-esque functionality:

```
<a href="#somewhere" data-scrollto>...</a>

$(document).on('click', 'a[data-scrollto]', function (e) {
  const target = $(this.hash);
  if (target.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
  }
});
```

**Class names**

Class names can also be coupled with CSS which is why they are quite favourable:

```
<a href="#somewhere" class="scroll-to">...</a>

$(document).on('click', 'a.scroll-to', function (e) {
  const target = $(this.hash);
  if (target.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
  }
});
```

But, if you really wanted to be lazy, apply the same method you're already using but exlcude the bootstrap links:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]:not([data-slide])', function (e) {
  const target = $(this.hash);
  if (target.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
  }
});
```